# WYSIWYG paste from word

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I installed WYSIWYG module with ckeditor library.
i had configured the text format and the ckeditor profile, but the only problem i'm facing is "pasting from word".

When i copy some content with colored text, some list and table, after i click on "paste from word" button, paste the content inside the textarea and hit ok, colors and the size of fonts and other formating disappear.

Any solution? thanks.

Content From Word:

[image]

Content When Pasting Using "Paste From Word":
[image]

Content After Ok:
[image]

Comment: You should never copy/paste from word, it introduces its own formatting. Use notepad or something similar.

Comment: I think that's by design, check out [the docs](http://ckeditor.com/addon/pastefromword). You might need to somehow diable the [`pasteFromWordRemoveStyles`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFromWordRemoveStyles) config option

Comment: i added the following to fckconfig.js file:
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
config.FromWordRemoveFontStyles = false; but it's not work

Comment: That's what past from word does. It *tries to* strip word markup out because generally the easiest and fastest way to break your site is to paste word formatting into it. If you want to keep the formattin, use the regular paste button, nt the paste from work one - however I would never recommend pasting from word.

Comment: also reqular paste do the same,however thanks for you help